# Android - Show and hide the text after time?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to show error messages and hide them after 3 seconds. That's what I have written but it seems that it doesn't work that way.

```
            yazi.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        yazi.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a Handler with its postDelayed method for your purpose:

```
//Show your view
yazi.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Hide your View after 3 seconds
        yazi.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}, 3000);
```

Comment: This one totally works! I think the other one would work, too. But this one is pretty much easier. Thanks!

Comment: @DenizALGIN this better than using thread. this solution does not create a new thread which is unnecessary. this is the right answer

Answer (score 0):

Update your code like this

Inside your onCreate() method

```
  yazi.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Thread thread=new Thread(runnable);
     thread.start();
```

and outside your onCreate() method , do like this

```
Runnable runnable=new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
          finally{


            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    yazi.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });
    }
};
};
```

Always use **runOnUiThread** for making UI operations.

Comment: 3 seconds sleep on UI thread? I don't think this is a solution.